# How can I link to a database server from another server?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, database

I'm going to launch a website in a few days, and I'm thinking of having one front-end server, and one MySQL database server. And my question is, if I want to read/write to the MySQL server from the front-end server, how should I link to that server. Is it when I connect to the host in PHP I should use an IP instead of localhost? I'm pretty new to this so maybe this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just change the connection string from localhost to the IP, network name, or FQDN.

Comment: How would I get the ip of the second server?

Comment: Lets say it like that: if you dont know it, then you have a problem. THis is like asking "where do I live?". You set up the servers, you know the IP you entered. Or your provider knows and you ask.

Comment: I didn't buy the servers yet that's why I'm asking :P And it's the first website I do, so that's way I don't have much info about this stuff.

Comment: If you install the machines yourself you'll have the IP.  If you are using a hosting provider they will provide you with the private IPs of the machines which you use in the connection string.